# Generalization of category algebra

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $\mathcal C$ be a category that has finitely many objects. The **category algebra** $R[\mathcal C]$ of $\mathcal C$ consists of finite sums $\sum a_i f_i$, where $f_i$ are morphisms of $\mathcal C$ and $a_i$ are elements of the ring $R$, with a multiplication operation
$$
\sum a_i f_i \cdot \sum b_j g_j =\sum a_ib_j f_i\circ g_j
$$
by using the composition $\circ$ in the category $\mathcal C$.

On the other hand, a **multicategory** $\mathcal D$ consists of objects, arrows, a composition operation, and identities, just like an ordinary category, the diﬀerence being that the domain of an arrow is not just a single object but a ﬁnite sequence of them.

**Question:** Could we imitate the construction of category algebras to define certain "multicategory algebra" $R[\mathcal D]$? If this sounds like a natural generalization, it seems strange to me since I can't find any reference. So, I'm afraid I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 5):

The category algebra is best understood in terms of the category algebroid: the free $R$-linear category generated by $C.$ The algebra just adds a bunch of zero products for non-composable morphisms because algebroids make some people nervous. You can generate an $R$-linear multicategory from a multicategory just as from a category, but it’s not very obvious how to make it into an $R$-algebra. Consider multimorphisms $f:(a,a)\to b$ and $g:(c)\to a.$ Then there’s no natural choice of $g\cdot f$ in your putative multicategory algebra. The problem is that multicategorical composition is just not a binary operation, not even a partial one.

Comment: Thank you! Probably, we should assume the domains of multimorphisms are all different (in particular, we may exclude $(a, a)$ as you mentioned). Then, we may likely make it into an $R$-algebra, I guess.

Comment: @Hang I guess. It’s not a very natural condition on a multicategory. Better to let the object you’re studying guide the construction rather than the other way around, I think.